# Make axios request pause in a loop based on response header

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios

I would like to make axios request to an API in a loop and pause the sending of new requests based on a response header of the API.

example code would be like this:

```
for(i in overallRequests) {
  const res = await axios(config);

  if (res.headers["ratelimit"] < 100) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 60000));
  }
}
```

this is not working as intended.

Comment: Did you mean `await` instead of `return`? Also you're missing a declaration for the `i` variable.

Comment: yes sorry `return` should be `await` in this case, which is still not working.

Comment: *How* is it not working? Are you getting error messages? What happens that you don't expect?

Answer (score -1):

Try for of loop instead of for in

```js
for(i of overallRequests) {
  const res = await axios(config);

  if (res.headers["ratelimit"] < 100) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 60000));
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).